# C# XML string element with Name attribute

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I am trying to create a c# object for serialization/deserialization with a string property.
The property needs to generate an element and also have an attribute:

eg:

```
...
<Comment Name="CommentName"></Comment>
...
```

If the property is a string, I cant see how to add the attribute, and if the comment is an object with Name and Value properties it generates:

```
...
<Comment Name="CommentName">
    <Value>comment value</Value>
</Comment>
...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to expose those 2 properties on a type and use the `[XmlText]` attribute to indicate that it shouldn't generate an extra element:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
public class Comment
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Comment Comment { get; set; }
}
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Customer cust = new Customer { Id = 1234,
            Comment = new Comment { Name = "abc", Value = "def"}};
        new XmlSerializer(cust.GetType()).Serialize(
            Console.Out, cust);
    }
}
```

If you want to flatten those properties onto the object itself (the `Customer` instance in my example), you would need extra code to make the object model pretend to fit what `XmlSerializer` wants, or a completely separate DTO model.